# Using Realm in Xamarin.Android app running in emulator throws RealmFileAccessErrorException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, realm

I'm trying to add Realm to my app (Xamarin Android). Starting with emulator first (Xaamrin android player - Nexus 5 with Android Lollipop).

[Github Issue here](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/542)

My code:

```
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MyActivitylayout);
        ....
        try
        {
            var path = AndroidIoHelper.CreateFileInAppFolder(AndroidIoHelper.GetAppDataFolder(), "tlm_db", "realm");

            var realm = Realm.GetInstance(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        .......
   }
```

Exception I'm getting:

> Realms.RealmFileAccessErrorException: Operation not permitted   at
>   Realms.NativeCommon.ExceptionThrower (IntPtr exceptionCode, IntPtr
>   utf8String, IntPtr stringLen) [0x0003b] in :0    at
>   (wrapper native-to-managed) Realms.NativeCommon:ExceptionThrower
>   (intptr,intptr,intptr)   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   Realms.NativeSharedRealm:open
>   (Realms.SchemaHandle,string,intptr,intptr,intptr,byte[],ulong) 05-15
>   12:57:18.384 I/mono-stdout( 5250):
>   Realms.RealmFileAccessErrorException: Operation not permitted 05-15
>   12:57:18.384 I/mono-stdout( 5250):   at
>   Realms.NativeCommon.ExceptionThrower (IntPtr exceptionCode, IntPtr
>   utf8String, IntPtr stringLen) [0x0003b] in :0  05-15
>   12:57:18.384 I/mono-stdout( 5250):   at (wrapper native-to-managed)
>   Realms.NativeCommon:ExceptionThrower (intptr,intptr,intptr) 05-15
>   12:57:18.385 I/mono-stdout( 5250):   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   Realms.NativeSharedRealm:open
>   (Realms.SchemaHandle,string,intptr,intptr,intptr,byte[],ulong) 05-15
>   12:57:18.385 I/mono-stdout( 5250):   at Realms.Realm.GetInstance
>   (Realms.RealmConfiguration config) [0x0010c] in :0 
>   05-15 12:57:18.385 I/mono-stdout( 5250):   at Realms.Realm.GetInstance
>   (System.String databasePath) [0x00019] in :0  05-15
>   12:57:18.385 I/mono-stdout( 5250):   at
>   MyApp.Activities.SplashScreenActivity+d__4.MoveNext ()
>   [0x00116] in
>   C:\Users***\Source\Repos\AppName\MyApp\Activities\SplashScreenActivity.cs:66
>   at Realms.Realm.GetInstance (Realms.RealmConfiguration config)
>   [0x0010c] in :0    at Realms.Realm.GetInstance
>   (System.String databasePath) [0x00019] in :0    at
>   MyApp.Activities.SplashScreenActivity+d__4.MoveNext ()
>   [0x00116] in
>   C:\Users***\Source\Repos\AppName\MyApp\Activities\SplashScreenActivity.cs:66

If I don't specify path I'm getting (`var realm = Realm.GetInstance();`):

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   type   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean
>   nonPublic) [0x00006] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:205
>   05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout( 5474): System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null. 05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout( 5474):
>   Parameter name: type 05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout( 5474):   at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>   [0x00006] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:205
>   05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout( 5474):   at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:147
>   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:147
>   at Realms.Realm.CreateRealmObjectMetadata (System.Type
>   realmObjectType) [0x0001e] in :0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement]
>   (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2
>   elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) [0x0004d] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:855
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement]
>   (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2
>   elementSelector) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:847
>   at Realms.Realm..ctor (Realms.SharedRealmHandle sharedRealmHandle,
>   Realms.RealmConfiguration config) [0x00037] in <filename unknown>:0
>
>   at Realms .Realm.GetInstance (Realms.RealmConfiguration config)
>   [0x00171] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   MyApp.Activities.SplashScreenActivity+<OnCreate>d__4.MoveNext ()
>   [0x00116] in
>   C:\Users\***\Source\Repos\AppName\MyApp\Activities\SplashScreenActivity.cs:66
>   05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout( 5474):   at
>   Realms.Realm.CreateRealmObjectMetadata (System.Type realmObjectType)
>   [0x0001e] in <filename unknown>:0  05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout(
>   5474):   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement]
>   (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2
>   elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) [0x0004d] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:855
>   05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout( 5474):   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement]
>   (IEnumerable`1 source, System.Func`2 keySelector, System.Func`2
>   elementSelector) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/mono/external/referencesource/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs:847
>   05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout( 5474):   at Realms.Realm..ctor
>   (Realms.SharedRealmHandle sharedRealmHandle, Realms.RealmConfiguration
>   config) [0x00037] in :0  05-15 13:05:05.257
>   I/mono-stdout( 5474):   at Realms.Realm.GetInstance
>   (Realms.RealmConfiguration config) [0x00171] in :0 
>   05-15 13:05:05.257 I/mono-stdout( 5474):   at
>   MyApp.Activities.SplashScreenActivity+d__4.MoveNext ()
>   [0x00116] in
>   C:\Users***\Source\Repos\AppName\MyApp\Activities\SplashScreenActivity.cs:66

The app has Write external storage permission.
Realm and Fody nuget packages installed properly, Fody weavers are present as expected..

It also crashes with same exception using HTC One X with Android 4.2

Comment: This question seems to have spawned a discussion here: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/542, in case anyone else hits this.

Answer (score 0):

The above attempt had other issues. There is a real bug currently in Realm with storage on *external* storage - see the issue https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/554 which is proving awkward to debug.